# extended IdentityUser Table coming Null c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

My IdentityUser Entity Class looking like this:

```
public class CoreUser: IdentityUser<string>
{
    public BEEUser BeeUser { get; set; }
}
```

And In my dbContext I specified the ForeignKey Like so:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<CoreUser>()
        .HasOne(a => a.BeeUser)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<BEEUser>(a => a.AspNetUsersId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

And this is what my BEEUser class looks like:

```
 public class BEEUser
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        
        public string AspNetUsersId { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }


        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

But When I do a findByUser function or anything my BeeUser always comes back as null and I have verified that both ids match in the database:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Include the BEEUser when getting the CoreUser
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data